# Textbox with a label in a GTK+ program

Tags: c, gtk, gnome

I am new to GTK+ programming.I wrote a simple GTK+ program where i display a label and a textbox in a window, the label should be to the left of the textbox and i should be able to specify the horizontal length of the textbox. Below is my code so far,the program runs fine but im unable to align the label to the left of the textbox and also set the textbox horizontal length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget,gpointer   data)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window,*table,*label,*entry;
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  void initialize_window(GtkWidget *);

  //Create the main window
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  initialize_window(window);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

   /* Create a 1x2 table */
   table = gtk_table_new (1, 2, TRUE);
   gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);
   gtk_widget_show (table);


  /* create a new label. */
  label = gtk_label_new ("Enter some text: ");
  gtk_misc_set_alignment (GTK_MISC (label), 0, 0);
  gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table),label, 0, 1, 0, 1);
  gtk_widget_show (label);

  //create a text box
  entry = gtk_entry_new ();
  gtk_entry_set_max_length (GTK_ENTRY (entry),0);
  gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table),entry, 0, 1, 0, 1);
  gtk_widget_show (entry); 



  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}



void initialize_window(GtkWidget *window)
{
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"My Window"); //Set window title
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 400, 200); //Set default size for the window
  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy",G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL); //End application when close button clicked

}
```

How can i fix this problem ?

Please help
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You messed with the table position and don't set aligin if you do not know what it does, it may be a bit missleading.
Here is working code (I think this is what you wanted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}



static void initialize_window(GtkWidget* window)
{
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"My Window"); //Set window title
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 400, 200); //Set default size for the window
  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL); //End application when close button clicked

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window,*table,*label,*entry;
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);


  //Create the main window
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  initialize_window(window);


   /* Create a 1x2 table */
   table = gtk_table_new (1, 2, TRUE);
   gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);


  /* create a new label. */
  label = gtk_label_new ("Enter some text:" );
  //gtk_misc_set_alignment (GTK_MISC (label), 0, 0);
  gtk_table_set_homogeneous(GTK_TABLE (table), TRUE);
  gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), label, 1, 2, 0, 1);


  //create a text box
  entry = gtk_entry_new ();
  gtk_entry_set_max_length (GTK_ENTRY (entry),0);
  gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), entry, 0, 1, 0, 1);


    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For alignment one can use hbox for horizontal arrangement or vbox for vertical arrangement.